# How to implement DoubleClick on Android EditText?

Tags: android, double-click, android-edittext

I have an "Activity1" which has an "EditText". I want to open another activity "Activity2" when the user Double clicks on the "EditText".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Open new activty here");
        return true;
    }
});
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!
"new OnTouchListener()" was not working i replaced it with
"new View.OnTouchListener()"

Comment: To fix Deprecation issue replace with final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {