# Textview multiple clicks in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application I have a TextView, when the user clicks for thr first time on it I have to arrange the data in descending order,When user click on the same text view once again I have to arrange the data in ascending order.Is there any way to accomplish this?

My Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean flag = false;
    db.open();
    Cursor c;
    if(flag==false)
    {
        c = db.getIncomeTitleDescitem(intent.getStringExtra("grpsdb"));
        startManagingCursor(c);
        flag=true;
    }                   
    else
    {
        System.out.println("inside else");
        c = db.getIncomeTitleAscitem(intent.getStringExtra("grpsdb"));
        startManagingCursor(c);
        flag=false;
    }
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);     
    String[] fromdes = new String[] {db.KEY_DATE,db.KEY_DESC,db.KEY_INCOME,db.KEY_TOTAL};
    int[] todes = new int[] {R.id.text1 ,R.id.text3,R.id.text5,R.id.text7};
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(IncomeDetails.this, R.layout.columnview, c, fromdes, todes);                          
    lv.setAdapter(notes);  
    db.close();             
}
```

Comment: check this i think this answer is suits for your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837601/how-to-implement-doubleclick-on-android-edittext

Comment: by the data you mean the text of the TextView???

Comment: ohhh why you are creating boolean flag inside onClick, it will keep on create, create only once ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily track with a flag, based on click update the flag.. flag you can keep as boolean or int whatever you want. For your reference...

```
boolean flag = false;   // false - first click, true - second click
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (flag == false) {
            flag = true;
            // do descending
         } else {
             flag = false;
             // do ascending
         }                
    }
});
```

Comment: i checked your code, you are doing a big mistake by creating boolean flag inside onClick. You should create one time and need to be track inside onClick... what else you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` to maintain the state.

By default set the TextView as `tv.setTag("descending");` then inside `onClick()` use `getTag()` and perform your work.

Sample,

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        String order = (String) paramView.getTag();
        if(order.equalsIgnoreCase("descending")){
            // perform descending ordering
            tv.setTag("ascending");
        }
        else if (order.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending")) {
            // perform ascending ordering
            tv.setTag("descending");
        } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

do you have the logics of arranging them in ascending and descending order?

If yes,

suppose the functions `arrangeA()` and `arrangeD()` do the arranging job, in ascending and descending order respectively.

```
String lastSet="none";
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(lastSet.equals("none")||lastSet.equals("asc")) {
            arrangeD();
            lastSet="desc";
        }
        else {
            arrngeA();
            lastSet="asc";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just place the

```
boolean flag = false;
```

above the function call

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

this will do your task

Answer (score 0):

boolean sortAscend = false

In your TextView's `onclicklistener()` check for `sortAscend` and sort it and set `sortAscend = !sortAscend`.

This way it will keep sorting it in asc/desc alternately